# Android devices best placed for being putting into monitor/promiscuous mode

Tags: wifi, android, smartphones

What Android devices are best placed for being putting into monitor/promiscuous mode? I asked on https://android.stackexchange.com/ and they suggested coming here.

I know the Nexus 5 is a good candidate but was looking at more recent devices such as Samsung S8 (onwards), Pixel 3 (onwards), One Plus One, Huawei etc

Thanks!